# Use a component in an other component in Angular

Tags: angular, components

I'm an new user of Angular and I work on a website to improve my learning. But there is something which I think is very simple but doesn't work.
I'm working on a motion designer portfolio where a component will be reuse to show the motion works. But at this point, I'm lost and I don't know how to organize all of this...
How to reuse the portfolio-card.component whith differents titles, images, url's and put it in my projects.component ?
Thanks for yout help! Cheers!

motion.ts

```
export interface Motion {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  url: string;
}
```

motion-mock.ts

```
export const Motions: Motion[] = [
  { "id": 1, "title": "Demoreel 2D/3D", "image": "", "url": "https://vimeo.com/314625743" },
  { "id": 2, "title": "Le défi Martin Fourcade MGEN 2018", "image": "", "url": "https://vimeo.com/260561771"},
  { "id": 3, "title": "Voeux 2018 SERCEL", "image": "", "url": "https://vimeo.com/251785754" },
]
```

portfolio-card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Motions } from './motion-mock.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portfolio-card',
  templateUrl: './portfolio-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portfolio-card.component.scss']
})
export class PortfolioCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

portfolio-card.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
  <div class="blog-entry">
    <div class="card" >
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{myMotion.image}}" alt="{{myMotion.title}}" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{motion.title}}</h4>
          <h5 class="card-text"></h5>
          <h5 class="card-text"><a href="{{myMotion.url}}">{{myMotion.title}}</a></h5>        
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

projects.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PortfolioCardComponent } from './portfolio-card/portfolio-card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = "Motion design";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Change your PortfolioCardComponent to accept motion as a parameter:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Motion } from './motion';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portfolio-card',
  templateUrl: './portfolio-card.component.html'
})
export class PortfolioCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myMotion: Motion;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

2. Change your projects.component.ts to get all motions:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = "Motion design";
    motions = Motions;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

3. Finally you can render all motions in your projects.component.html:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="motions">
  <app-portfolio-card [myMotion]="item"></app-portfolio-card>
</ng-template>
```

See the working example by this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxrrbu

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your feedback resolves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to import it inside `projects.component.ts`.

Instead,

import it into your module.ts file and add it to `declarations` array.

and in project.component.html file use it like this,

```
<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
...
<app-portfolio-card></app-portfolio-card>
...
```

wherever you want.